# ListView muito comprida

Tags: android, android-layout

Criei uma `ListView` que apresenta as musicas do meu sdcard, só que como pode ver na imagem abaixo ela esta muito comprida independente da quantidade de itens, quero que a altura dela fique menor para exibir mais nomes, para que a lista não fique extensa de mais, e também esta muito feio desse jeito.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código xml da tela:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Musica" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnVoltar"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnVoltar"
    android:text="Voltar"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="Takion"
    android:textColor="#32CD32"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvPlaylist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

</ListView>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnVoltar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lvPlaylist"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:src="@drawable/back" />
```

Classe Player (tela com botoes de play, next, ect, seekBar...):

```
public class Player extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

SeekBar music=null;   
AudioManager mgr=null;

static MediaPlayer mp;
ArrayList<File> mySongs;
int position;
Uri u;

Thread updateSeekBar;

ImageButton btnVoltar, btnBackward, btnPrevious, btnNext, btnForward;

private ImageButton btnPlayPause;
private boolean isbtnPlayer = false;
SeekBar progressMusic;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

    mgr=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    music=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.sbMusic);

    initBar(music, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    btnVoltar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnVoltar);
    btnBackward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBackward);
    btnPrevious = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
    btnPlayPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlayPause);
    btnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    btnForward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnForward);       

    btnBackward.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnPlayPause.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnForward.setOnClickListener(this);

    progressMusic = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.progressMusic);
    updateSeekBar = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
            int currentPosition = 0;
            while (currentPosition < totalDuration){
                try {
                    sleep(500);
                    currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                    progressMusic.setProgress(currentPosition);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    };

    if(mp!=null){
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();

    }

    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle b = i.getExtras();
    mySongs = (ArrayList) b.getParcelableArrayList("songlist");
    position = b.getInt("pos", 0);

    u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
    mp.start();

    progressMusic.setMax(mp.getDuration());

    updateSeekBar.start();

    progressMusic.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            mp.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        }
    });

    btnVoltar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {       

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent home = new Intent(Player.this, Musica.class);
            Player.this.startActivity(home);
            Player.this.finish();

        }
    });
}

 private void initBar(SeekBar bar, final int stream) {
        bar.setMax(mgr.getStreamMaxVolume(stream));
        bar.setProgress(mgr.getStreamVolume(stream));

        bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
          public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar, int progress,
                                        boolean fromUser) {
            mgr.setStreamVolume(stream, progress,
                                AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
          }

          public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {

          }

          public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {

          }
        });
      }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.btnPlayPause:
            if(mp.isPlaying()){                 
                isbtnPlayer = true;
                btnPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.player);
                mp.pause();
            }else{
                isbtnPlayer = true;
                btnPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                mp.start();
            }break;

        case R.id.btnForward:
            mp.seekTo(mp.getCurrentPosition()+5000);
            break;

        case R.id.btnBackward:
            mp.seekTo(mp.getCurrentPosition()-5000);
            break;

        case R.id.btnNext:
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            position = (position+1) %mySongs.size();
            u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
            mp.start();
            progressMusic.setMax(mp.getDuration());
            break;

        case R.id.btnPrevious:
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            position = (position-1 < 0)? mySongs.size()-1: position-1;
            u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
            mp.start();
            progressMusic.setMax(mp.getDuration());
            break;              
    }

}
```

Classe Musica (Apresenta o listView com as musica):

```
public class Musica extends Activity {

ListView lv;

String[] items;

ImageButton btnVoltar;

ImageButton btnBack;    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.musica);        

    btnVoltar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnVoltar);
    btnVoltar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent home = new Intent(Musica.this, Home.class);
            Musica.this.startActivity(home);
            Musica.this.finish();

        }
    });

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvPlaylist);

    final ArrayList<File> mySongs = findSongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

    items = new String[ mySongs.size() ];

    for(int i = 0; i<mySongs.size(); i++){

        //toast(mySongs.get(i).getName().toString());
        items[i] = mySongs.get(i).getName().toString().replace(".mp3", "").replace(".wav", "");

    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.player, R.id.tvPlayer, items);
    lv.setAdapter(adp);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Player.class).putExtra("pos", position).putExtra("songlist", mySongs));
        }

    });

}

public ArrayList<File> findSongs(File root){
    ArrayList<File> al = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] files = root.listFiles();
    for(File singleFile : files){
        if(singleFile.isDirectory() && !singleFile.isHidden()){
            al.addAll(findSongs(singleFile));               
        }else{
            if(singleFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3") || singleFile.getName().endsWith(".wav")){
                al.add(singleFile);
            }               
        }           
    }       
    return al;
}   

public void toast(String text){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

RelativeLayout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPlayer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />
```

Comment: Poderia colocar o código dos seus itens da lista? O XML que você fez para utilizar no getView() do Adapter desse listView.

Comment: @GustavoBitencourt pronto postei todos os códigos.

Comment: Desculpa, mas seu código está confuso.

Tente utilizar android:layout_width="wrap_content" no ListView.

Comment: Mais você conhece algum método para diminuir a listView? Nao precisa entender o código só quero um exemplo de como fazer isso.

Comment: infelizmente não funciona só alterando o `width`, já tentei não deu certo.

Answer (score 1):

Busque a utilização das Listas personalizadas no Android utilizando Adapters. Procure trabalhar com a implementação desta forma pois ela permite que você defina o Layout de cada linha que será apresentada.

Existe muito material na internet mostrando como se implementar. Sugiro que realize uma pesquisa a respeito para melhor entendimento.

Uma outra dica que posso te oferecer é a implementação de RecyclerView no lugar da ListView tradicional. Ele é uma "evolução" com melhoramento de performance para sua aplicação.

Aqui existe um exemplo mostrando como é aplicação do ListView:
[Personalizando uma ListView no Android](http://blog.alura.com.br/personalizando-uma-listview-no-android/)

O conteúdo é do pessoal do Alura que é uma plataforma de ensino online que gostei muito e recomendo o material deles: [Site Alura](https://www.alura.com.br/)

Neste Link existe um exemplo para implementar o RecyclerView e foi escrito por Rafael de Araújo (muito bem escrito por sinal): [Listas com RecyclerView](https://medium.com/android-dev-br/listas-com-recyclerview-d3f41e0d653c)

Fica aqui minha contribuição para sua implementação. Acredito que seguindo elas e observando as demais respostas dos colegas você conseguirá uma boa implementação com um excelente desempenho no seu App.

Answer (score 0):

O fator não é apenas diminuir a listView, mas colocar do tamanho que você quer. Sabemos que match_parent, faz com que ele se estenda do tamanho do componente pai, e wrap_content, faz com que o componente fique do tamanho que satisfazer os dados contidos nele.
Então, analisando o seu código, eu tentaria mexer em duas três coisas:

1. Trocar o match_parent por android:layout_width="wrap_content" no
   componente ListView.
2. Analisar o funcionamento do trecho:
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
3. Analisar o elemento pai da ListView, que no caso é o
   RelativeLayout.

Espero ter ajudado!

Boa sorte!

Comment: já troquei o `layout_width="wrap_content"`, removi o `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);` e não funcionou e o elemento Pai eu adicionei na pergunta, se poder dar uma olhada mais não vejo nada que possa estender o listView desse jeito.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um layout xml para a linha do ListView.

row_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

E criar seu ArrayAdapter extendendo de `ArrayAdapter`

```
public class myArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SUA_CLASSE>{

    Context context;


    public myArrayAdapter (Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, R.layout.row_layout);
        this.context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);

        SUA_CLASSE p = this.getItem(position);

        txtName = TextView rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtName.setText(SUA_CLASSE.toString());

        return rowView;
    }


    @Override
    public void add(SUA_CLASSE object) {
        super.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public SUA_CLASSE getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.getItem(position);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

O problema pode estar aqui

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"` do listview

Esse trecho do código pode fazer com que o seu getView do adapter seja chamado infinitamente e também ocorrer o problema que acontece com você, o layout do ListView dever ter altura definida em `match_parent` caso você não queira oculpar a tela inteira com `match_parent`, pense em usar weighsum e layout_weight para trabalhar com "porcentagens". Lembrando que para isso dever estar dentro de um LinearLayout.

exemplo:

```
<LinearLayout
android:wheigthsum=1 <!-- as somas dos layout_weight deve ser 1 == 100% -->
 ...>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height=0dp
        android:layout_weight=0.3 <!-- 30% -->
        ...>
        <!-- cabeçalho, alguns textviews ou outros componentes aqui -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height=0dp
        android:wheigthsum=0.5 <!-- 50% -->
        ...>
        <!-- implementa seu listview aqui -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvPlaylist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height=0dp
        android:layout_weight=0.2 <!-- 20% -->
        ...>
        <!-- rodapé, alguns textviews ou outros componentes aqui -->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve utilizar margens ou algum componente para limitar o tamanho. Caso você queira deixar somente a lista na tela, mas não preenchendo tudo, adicione margens, caso queira preencher este espaço com outro componente, use belowof ou aboveof do relative layout. Lembrando, que se seu aplicativo suporta diferentes telas, implemente outros layouts e usando rightof ou leftof ao invés de belowof.

Answer (score 0):

O problema provavelmente esta no seu arquivo de layout "player", não deu para entender completamente sua explicação mas acredito que esse seu arquivo tenha um RelativeLayout com um TextView, você deve colocar a propriedade "layout_height" dos dois como "wrap_content" dessa forma irá resolver o problema.